# How to convert UTF-8 string to japanese or any other language IText PDF?

Tags: java, xml, pdf, encoding, utf-8

I am parsing the XML using UTF-8 encoding which has some Chinese,japanese or kannada I am able to display the languages in the screen(HTML) page successfully but I wanted to generate the PDF I see only English...

I came across the Fonts but worried like have fonts for each and every language(sorry if am wrong).

In debug mode I am able to see Chinese and other languages in variable when it is converted to UTF -8 I see ?????????.

```
                            new String(myString.getBytes(Charset.forName("ISO-8859-1")),
                                    Charset.forName("UTF-8"))
```

Please help to display any languages in IText pdf

> NOTE:I am parsing the XML using UTF-8,When I fetch from DB without using UTF or anything I am able to print in excel...in PDF I think I should use fonts.

Comment: It sounds like you haven't sufficiently debugged this problem yourself yet. For instance, why are you trying to solve "showing unicode characters" by setting an encoding, instead of making sure the PDF generation code sets the correct font stack? Without code that shows what you're trying right now, as a [mcve], we have no idea what you're actually doing wrong, and your description doesn't give enough information for us to go on. Please give [how to ask a good question](/help/how-to-ask) a quick reread and adjust your post accordingly.

Comment: It doesn't matter what the XML document encoding is (as long as you do read the document with that encoding); All text values in an XML document are in Unicode. (A library would probably do this better than a bespoke implementation.)

Comment: This is Java, isn't it? Please [edit] to add tag. Java strings are also Unicode (UTF-16). Your code is a lossy conversion from a Java string (UTF-16) to ISO 8859-1 followed data-corrupting conversion from UTF-8, ending up again with a Java string (UTF-16).

Comment: `new String(myString.getBytes(Charset.forName("ISO-8859-1")),
                                    Charset.forName("UTF-8"))` - if such a conversion is necessary to properly retrieve your input data, there already is something fishy about the way you get that `myString`. That been said, your question appears to be about iText but neither do you in any way show how you are handling your data with iText nor do you explain what the undesired effect is or what you actually want.

Answer (score 1):

UTF-8 is able to represent text in all languages.  ISO-8859-1 is only able to represent text in English and most text in a handful of European languages.

If you are converting text to ISO-8859-1 and then storing it as UTF-8 you are breaking support for text in other languages not supported by the limited subset of ISO-8859-1.  Keep it in a Unicode form (eg. UTF-8).

As has been mentioned in the comments, Java strings are internally Unicode-compatible (they use UTF-16 internally) and so there is no need for any conversion, even to UTF-8, to fully support all languages.  You would only need to convert if you need to do so for whatever you are using to export to PDF, but it doesn't seem like you've specified what that is.

Comment: thanks for help...I got your point I am able to print the languages in excel report...without using UTF-8 or anything just get the data and print...but PDF Itext is not displaying those text(Japanese and all at all)..came across using fonts in IText

Comment: @GopiLal *"but PDF Itext is not displaying those text"* - then simply do show the pivotal code of your iText usage, so people here can analyse it and tell you what you do wrong.